# Bash Script - How to escape JWT in curl correctly

Tags: linux, bash, mac-osx, curl, escaping

Im trying to just execute some curl commands against an API from within a bash script. I wrote it on Mac OS and the thing ran without issues. I started executing it on linux and found some strange behavior which i cannot wrap my head around. Basically on the original version on OSX, i ran the command like this:

```
var=$(curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -X GET "https://some.host.com/path1/${var1}/path1/${var2}/?api-version=2010-10-10&\$filter=someFilter()" 2>/dev/null)
```

Somehow the JWT messes up the variable on linux. I did some debugging and landed on this:

```
METHOD="GET"
URI="https://some.host.com/path1/${var1}/path1/${var2}/?api-version=2010-10-10&\$filter=someFilter()"
cmd="curl -H Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN -X $METHOD $URI"
echo $cmd
```

Executing this on linux outputs the variable in a messed up way:

```
curl -H Authorization: Bearer YYYYYYYYYY -X GET  https://some.host.com/path1/foo/path1/bar/?api-version=2010-10-10&$filter=someFilter()XXXXXXXXXX
```

I obfuscated the JWT for obvious reasons. The Y part is 3420 characters long and the X part is 98 characters (Does not add up to full JWT length)

Well then i tought i'll escape the stuff, tried and failed as well:

```
cmd="curl -H Authorization: Bearer \"$TOKEN\" -X \"$METHOD\" \"$URI\""
```

Bash sets the ending " of the TOKEN somewhere in the middle of the JWT (after 3419 characters) and messes up the variable again.

It feels like it should be quite obvious whats going on but i cannot figure out how to escape the stuff properly.

Comment: Don't store commands in shell variables, it's a parsing nightmare. It's simplest and most reliable to just execute commands directly. If you need to store a command, use a function (or possibly an array). See [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), ["Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)